# Delphi RESTClient Joomla get user token

Tags: authentication, delphi, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am attempting to use TRESTClient/REST Debugger to get the User ID and token from a Joomla website.

The url is as follows:

For the Login API Call Please provide the Username and password in the API request body - https://thesite.com/index.php?app=users&resource=login&option=com_api&format=raw

The request must contain 2 values:

1. key-> username, value-> exampleUser
2. key-> password, value-> xyz

I am failing to get the correct response. I am able to get results from other resources from the same website, but this I am only getting an empty body.

[image]

Comment: If you are a Joomla user/developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the parameter type of the *username* and *password* parameter to BODY instead of GET/POST. This will place them into the request body instead of the URL.